# Camel Properties file load from Junit Integration Test

Tags: apache-camel, jboss-arquillian

I have a Camel Route which uses CDI to load a properties file from the JBoss configuration directory ...***works perfect***.

What I need to do is load one of the properties that are loaded in 
an Arquillian integration test I am writing.

Example:

Content of Fiddler.properties file in the JBoss configuration   directory

silly.value     =   Laughing
serious.value   =   politics

Example Producer class to load properties

```
     /**  
      * Create the Camel properties component using CDI @Produces  
      */  
        @Produces  
        @Named("properties")  
        PropertiesComponent propertiesComponent() {  
            final PropertiesComponent component = new PropertiesComponent();

            // load JBoss properties file  
            component.setLocation(  
             "file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/fiddler.properties"
            );
            return component;
        }
```

A given property from the Fiddler.properties file is now available  in the main Camel route as **{{silly.value}}** or **{{serious.value}}**

**Problem:**

What I would like to do is load/reference one of these property values from my Arquillian Integration Test … probably in the @BeforeClass method …something like below:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MainRouteIT {

.
.
Boolean allOK = false;

@BeforeClass
public static void setupTest() throws Exception {
    allOK = new testCheck(
                        {{silly.value}}, {{serious.value}}
                      );
 .
 .
```

Any idea if something like this is possible in Camel within an Arquillian test ?

Comment: Well ...I have one way ...almost :

Comment: Properties p = new Properties(); 
    final String jbossCfgDir = System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.dir"); 
    final File inpPropFile = new File(jbossCfgDir, "DEV_PROPS/fiddler.properties"); 
    p.load(IOUtils.toBufferedInputStream(FileUtils.openInputStream(inpPropFile)));

Comment: Only issue is that System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.dir") keeps returning null :=(

Comment: maybe there is some ENV variable that points to the jboss server config dir og jboss server dir so you can then use that instead of JVM system properties.

Comment: @BeforeClass runs on the client side and not in the container. Hence the expected system property is not available. You could try setting up the system property yourself by configuring it <systemPropertyVariables> on the maven-surefire-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution we are using (but without Arquillian):

First define a CDI alternative for the Camel "properties" component, which will use testing property values.

Then annotate your unit test in order to use the alternate producers of Camel components.

```
@Alternative
public class CamelAlternatives {

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Named("properties")
    public PropertiesComponent propertiesComponent() {      
        PropertiesComponent component = new PropertiesComponent();      
        component.setLocations( Arrays.asList("classpath:common.properties", "classpath:testing.properties") );
        return component;
    }

@RunWith(CamelCdiRunner.class)
@Beans(alternatives = {CamelAlternatives.class})
public class MyUnitTest {
    ...
}
```